# Tippy.js unwanted effect in IE 11

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, popover, popper.js

I'm using Tippy.js to create custom dropdowns and popovers in my app. I have them configured to display immediately on click. No effects. Everything works as expected in all browsers except Internet Explorer 11. When a target element is clicked, the tip comes flying in from the top of the viewport (either left or right depending on "placement" config). Is there a configuration I'm missing in Tippy.js or Popper.js (dependency) or is this an IE bug? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`option {flipDuration: 0}` solved it for me

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the assist.